# Is it possible to check if a value is an int in C#?

Tags: c#

Hey so I'm currently working on a game in unity with a friend mine and we're trying to get the movement of our AI down. Seeing as I'm not currently fluent in C# I was wondering if there was a way to check if a value can be considered as an int (As in, a whole number). The code I want to use this for is here:

```
while(transform.position != int){
            //Does the actual visual moving
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, monsterPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: What type is `position`? A `dynamic`? A floating point that might or might not be whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the % mod operator, to see if there's a remainder:

```
if(transform.position % 1 == 0)
{
    //It's a whole number
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I totally forgot about this operation. I'll blame the beer.